# statistics question about two random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint pdf:
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac35x(y + y^2)  & \text{if }0<x<2\text{ and } 0 < y < 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Find $\Pr(Y > X)$.

- **A 27/200**
- B 27/140
- C 1/2
- D 33/150

The correct answer is A but I can't reach it. Any suggestions as to how I can solve it?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Draw a  $2 \times 1$ rectangle in the $xy$-axis and integrate the cdf in the region of the rectangle where $Y>X$. Note this region can be described in terms of the line $Y=X$.

Answer (score 0):

To be found is the integral $$\int\int f\left(x,y\right)\left[y>x\right]dxdy$$
where $\left[y>x\right]=1$ if $y>x$ and $\left[y>x\right]=0$ otherwise.

This comes to the same as finding $$\frac{3}{5}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}x\left(y+y^2\right)dxdy$$

Can you take it from here?